# Creating a view from an SQL table ordering by multiple columns treating them independently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am working on a SQL view which extracts data from a table with multiple columns in it sorted by a single column, but I want the view to return the data such and put it into different columns sorted by its own column without being considering whether the data belongs to a single record or not.

For Example, 
I am creating a view which returns two columns named `Give` and `Ask` from a table in which there are four records for `ID(0,1,2,3)`,  `Give (100, 90, 75, 60)` and `Ask` column as `NULL, 110, 99, 100.` I have been able to create a view which return these values in the following order

```
Give   Ask
100    NULL
90     110
75     99
60     100
```

But I want the view which returns something like following

```
 Give   Ask
 100    99
 90     100
 75     110
 60     NULL
```

As we can see from above that the Give column is not related to Ask Column after running a view i.e., in the original SQL table the record for Give and Ask values for ID 0 are 100 and NULL respectively but in the view the values of Give and Ask for first record are 100 and 99  in which Give is in Descending order and ask is in ascending order.

May I know a better way to achieve this.

I have the following query for the view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Result]
AS

with CTE as(
SELECT distinct
   CC.Product,
   CC.Term,   
   iCC.Give,
   iCC.Ask


   FROM Cust CC
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 3
                Give,
                Ask, 

             FROM Cust iCC
             WHERE CC.Term = iCC.Term and CC.Product = iCC.Product
             ORDER BY iCC.Give DESC, iCC.Ask ASC) iCC)
             select Product, Term, Give, givelabel as label from CTE 
             union
             select Product, Term, Ask, asklabel from CTE 

GO
```

Comment: This should be a job for your business logic layer.

Comment: @Crono Is that not possible with a view because I dont want to alter the sql table

Comment: You don't need to alter the sql table. What I'm saying is that the solution to your problem doesn't have to be solved with a view.

Comment: @Crono. Thanks but I have been using this view in most of my applications and I just dont want to go for something else other than view because it makes me to do changes in many places

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to get the order of a particular row value within the full column, in either ascending or descending direction. You can make more than one ROW_NUMBER() calculation in a query. So you can get a query which shows where each field's value would be, if independently sorted. But you can't actually break apart the columns of an individual table and differently sort them. You can, however, take two copies of the table, independently sort them, and then JOIN them back together. The trick is how you JOIN them back together. You can't JOIN them by the original ID, because in your final results, the "Give" might come from one ID and the "Ask" might come from another. You essentially have to tell SQL Server to line up the columns exactly as you ordered them. You can do that by having a row number in each newly ordered table and then JOINing by that row number. That's essentially what's done in the below example query which returns the results you specified.

The one trick is that you want NULL values to be on the bottom (at least in the ASK column), which means that the NULL values have to be the largest values in the column, even though SQL Server naturally puts them as the smallest values. You can use isNull to replace the NULLs with the maximum value for the chosen data type (2147483647 being the maximum integer for the example below). The NULLs in the Give column will naturally be at the bottom because they are considered the "smallest" and it is sorted in descending order.

```
DECLARE @GiveAsk TABLE
(
    ID int,
    Give int,
    Ask int
)
INSERT INTO @GiveAsk (ID, Give, Ask) VALUES (0, 100, NULL);
INSERT INTO @GiveAsk (ID, Give, Ask) VALUES (1, 90, 110);
INSERT INTO @GiveAsk (ID, Give, Ask) VALUES (2, 75, 99);
INSERT INTO @GiveAsk (ID, Give, Ask) VALUES (3, 60, 100);

WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Give DESC) AS GiveOrder,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY isNull(Ask,2147483647)) AS AskOrder,
        Give,
        Ask
    FROM        @GiveAsk
)
SELECT      b1.Give,
            b2.Ask
FROM        BaseData b1
JOIN        BaseData b2
ON          b1.GiveOrder = b2.AskOrder
ORDER BY    b1.GiveOrder;

WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Give DESC) AS GiveOrder,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY isNull(Ask,2147483647)) AS AskOrder,
        Give,
        Ask
    FROM        @GiveAsk
)
SELECT      b1.Give,
            b2.Ask
FROM        BaseData b1
JOIN        BaseData b2
ON          b1.GiveOrder = b2.AskOrder
ORDER BY    b1.GiveOrder;
```